# Is anyone experiencing style issues in kendo datepicker?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

[image]

I'm having issues with kendo datepicker styles.
Is anyone experiencing this.

My angular version - `"@angular/cli": "^8.1.0".`

Kendo version -

```
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^4.4.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^3.7.4",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^3.12.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "3.5.4",
"@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^2.4.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^3.14.4",
"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^3.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.7.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.4.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^1.4.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^3.3.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^2.6.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^1.2.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^4.3.2",
"@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.1",
"@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.5.12",
"@progress/kendo-theme-default": "latest",
```

I tried updating kendo versions to the latest and it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you use `ng add ...` to add your kendo package?

Comment: It was working until I updated angular 6 to 8.
now i temporarily fixed with CSS 
.k-calendar-navigation .k-calendar-navigation-highlight {
    top: 55% !important;
}